# Convert Pandas Distance Matrix DataFrame to Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distance-matrix

I have a pandas DataFrame with n ids as columns and indices. Is there some easy method that I'm not considering to convert this to n<sup>2</sup> rows of distances like so?

```
    id1 id2
id1   0 .75
id2 .75   0
```

to

```
id1   id2    .75
id1   id1      0
id2   id2      0
id2   id1    .75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`stack()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
>>> df.stack()
id1  id1    0.00
     id2    0.75
id2  id1    0.75
     id2    0.00
dtype: float64
```

This creates a Series with a MultiIndex - the distances in your original  DataFrame become the values. This generalises to any shape of DataFrame.